# Remove file from URL

Tags: html, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My current URL structure is `example.com/blog/blog-post`, but I would like it to display example.com/blog-post without moving the files location. My site is using IIS to host an HTML website. Is this possible and if so how can I achieve it / learn how to do it? Thanks!

Comment: Please clerify your question. You're telling us your URL is the same as what you would like to display. It doesn't make any sense.

Comment: are you using wordpress?

Comment: @icecub it's pretty simple, the poster wants to know how to do URL rewrites but hasn't bothered to google the topic before asking here.

Comment: My current URL is /blog/blog-post, and the URL I would like is /blog-post. I don't want to move the blog-post file into the home directory as that will clutter up fast, so I was asking if there was a way to do this via some code.

Comment: And I did do a lot of research before posting. I've been trying to figure out how to use rewrite functions for hours but nobody has an example that's similar to mine.

Answer (score 0):

Please look here to get you started on URL rewriting.

https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

If only for a few pages, you could also survive with simple redirection - this can be done directly in the HTML head:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='http://example.com/blog/blog-post'" />
```